# Valgrind: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) - opening file

Tags: c, valgrind

[EDIT]: I added full code.

I have to create a simple version of "grep" command on unix systems in C. Everything is working fine, only Valgrind says `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`.
I think, it might be connected to the file, that I am trying to open. Please see my code bellow.
Please note, that I can't use `<string.h>` in my code.
I compile the code with clang on Ubuntu:

`cc -pedantic -Wall -Werror -g -std=c99 grep.c -o program`

This is what Valgrind says:

```
lukas@lukas-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/shared/Lab04/prg-hw04$ valgrind --track-origins=yes ./program Mem /proc/meminfo
==2588== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2588== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2588== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2588== Command: ./program Mem /proc/meminfo
==2588== 
==2588== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2588==    at 0x4C32D08: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2588==    by 0x4EBC9D1: puts (ioputs.c:35)
==2588==    by 0x108970: check (grep.c:14)
==2588==    by 0x108AA9: read (grep.c:50)
==2588==    by 0x108B66: main (grep.c:71)
==2588==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2588==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2588==    by 0x108A04: read (grep.c:33)
==2588==    by 0x108B66: main (grep.c:71)
==2588== 
MemTotal:       10461696 kB
MemFree:         7701488 kB
MemAvailable:    8480772 kB
==2588== 
==2588== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2588==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2588==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 2,700 bytes allocated
==2588== 
==2588== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2588== 
==2588== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2588== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Could you help me with locating the problem?
This is my grep.c file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 100
int printed = 1;    // return value -> 0 for patter found, 1 for pattern not found
char *pattern;
char *dest;

void check(char *line, int length, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (line[i] == pattern[0]) {
            for (int j = 1; j < size && (i+j) < length; j++) {
                if (line[i+j] == pattern[j]) {
                    if (j==size-1) {
                        printf("%s\n", line);   // print line
                        printed = 0;    // pattern found
                        goto END;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    END: ;
}

void read(void) {       // read lines, then check individual lines
    int c;
    int lengthPat = 0; 
    while(pattern[++lengthPat] != '\0');    // check length of pattern - I can't use string.h library
    FILE *file = fopen(dest, "r");
    size_t size =100;
    char *line = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    if (line == NULL)   //succesfully created malloc?
        exit(102);
    int last = 0;
    if (file != NULL) {     // file succesfully opened
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {   
             if (c != '\n') {       // read line until \n
                if(last ==size)  {
                    char *p_line = realloc(line, 2*size*sizeof(char));
                    if (p_line == NULL)
                        free(line);
                    line = p_line;
                    size *= 2;
                }
                line[last++] = (char)c;
             }
             else {             // end of line, check for pattern
                check(line, last, lengthPat);
                last = 0; 
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {    
                    line[i] = '\0';
                }
             }
        }
        fclose(file);
        free(line);
    }
    else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open file!\n");
    }
}

/* The main program */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    if (argc == 3) {
        pattern = argv[1];
        dest = argv[2];
        read();
    }
    return printed;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see how to provide a [mcve]. In particular, it would be helpful to either have `check` included in the code you've posted here (if the issue is not reproducible without it), or dropped entirely (if it is). (you may also find the [tour] and [help] interesting).

Comment: please copy/paste that actual error statement from valgrind into your question.

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE *file = fopen(dest, "r");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "my error message");` to output to `stderr`, both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (c != (int)'\n')`  the expression: '\n' is already a `int`, so no need to cast it

Comment: OT:  regarding: `if (argc == 3) {`  What if the function parameter `argc` is NOT 3?  Then should output a USAGE statement similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <pattern> <destination>\n", argv[0] );'  followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   Where both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are in the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: OT: regarding: `while(pattern[++size] != '\0');`  much more clear to just call `strlen( pattern );`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
                {    
                    line[i] = '\0';
                }`  this would be much clearer if written as:  `memset( line, '\0', sizeof(line) );`  Note: `memset()` is found in the header file: `string.h`

Comment: OT: regarding: `check(last, size); //function, that compares the line and pattern`  actually this only compares the length of `pattern` and `line`.  If it actually compares the two, then a better statement would be: `if( strcmp( pattern, line ) == 0 )` to check for a match

Comment: the `check()` function is not posted, so (at least) include prototype statement of: `void check( int, int );`

Comment: using the `gcc` compiler, with the options: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`, it only outputs a warning about a missing definition/prototype for the function: `check()`  `gcc` is very good about warning about uninitialized variables, so exactly where is the problem?

Comment: Thank you @user3629249. I can't use string.h, therefore I don't use neither 'memset' nor 'strlen'.
I added the whole code.

Comment: the valgrind messages say that the line being processed is not NUL terminated the first time through the processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"connected to the file" is the key.

Your input file has lines longer than 100 characters. Replace stack array with dynamically growing heap array.

```
size_t size =100;
char c_line = malloc(size);

...
if(last ==size) 
     line = c_line = realloc(c_line, size<<=1);
```

On fixing that, the mistake is on this line:

```
printf("%s\n", line);   // print line
```

`line` is not null terminated so using printf is an advanced topic. We do this instead:

```
for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)
    putc(line[k], stdout);
putc(line[k], stdout);
```

Comment: Thank you @Joshua. Unfortunately this didn't help, please see my first post, i made an edit.

Comment: @LAKY911: I think I found the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was missing null terminator `\0` at the end of the string `line`. 
Thanks all for help.